# Python. Extraer objeto al azar de una lista

Tags: python

El problema es que tengo una lista `"l"` de la que quiero seleccionar un item aleatorio varias veces sin repetirlo, y no se como hacerlo. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
import random

l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

sel1 = random.choice(l)
```

Hasta ahí bien, pero ahora quiero definir un `"sel2"` que sea un elemento al azar de `"l"` pero *distinto* de `"sel1"`. Y así poder seguir definiendo un `"sel3"` *distinto* de `"sel1"` y `"sel2"`.

Gracias de antemano =)

Answer (score 3):

Podrías darle otro enfoque a tu problema: ¿por qué no desordenar la lista e ir sacando cada elemento de la misma?

La función `shuffle` te permite desordenar los elementos en una lista. Mira este ejemplo:

```
from random import shuffle

list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
shuffle(list) # list -> ["c", "a", "d", "b"]

sel1 = list[0] # "c"
sel2 = list[1] # "a"
....
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

En lugar de elegir aleatoriamente elemento por elemento, haz una ordenación al azar de toda la lista:

```
l2 = l[:]  # copia de la lista
random.shuffle(l2)

sel1, sel2, sel3 = l2[:3]
```

o más sencillo, usa `random.sample`:

```
sel1, sel2, sel3 = random.sample(l, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random as rd

rd.sample(lista, k = n)
```

n es el número de elementos que quieres extraer sin repeticiones de tu lista.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esta pequeña función:

```
import random
def random_sin_repetir(lista):
    for _ in range(0,len(lista)):
        result = random.choice(lista)
        yield result
        lista.remove(result)
```

Puedes comprobar los resultados con:

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
[i for i in random_sin_repetir(lista)]
```

> > ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
[i for i in random_sin_repetir(lista)]
```

> > ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a']

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo que proponéis puede ser una buena solución si los elementos que contiene la lista no están repetido, si los elementos pudieran estar definidos varias veces dentro de la lista inicialmente tendríamos que encontrar cuales son los elementos distintos.

Una posible solución para eliminar elementos repetidos podría ser:

```
lista_original = list(set(lista_original))
```

Otras posibles formas:
http://blog.elcodiguero.com/python/eliminar-objetos-repetidos-de-una-lista.html